# setNavigationBarHidden:NO Not Working after removeFromSuperview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I am adding a UIWebView subview on top of my Detail View Controller which has a navigation bar. I would like to hide the navigation bar when in the WebView subview and reveal it again when removing from the superview, so that there is more screen room while viewing the WebView.

The problem with my code is that the navigation bar is successfully hidden after adding the subview, but it doesn't work when trying to reveal the navigation bar again when the subview is removed.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

This is my code:

```
// In InstrumentsDetailViewController.m

- (IBAction)edu1Link:(id)sender {

    _webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc]
                          initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:_webViewController.view];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


// In WebViewController.m

- (IBAction) doneButton:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                           forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` be in your `InstrumentsDetailViewController`? To me, it seems that you are trying to show the navigation controller of a view you have just removed.

Comment: Try replacing `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` with `[[[self parentViewController] navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` That should call the `parentViewController`

Comment: SimonBS, thank you for the quick reply. It seemed like a very good solution, but I tried it and it didn't work. Do you have any idea why it wouldn't work, since it does seem that the Controller in superview should be the parentViewController?

Comment: Certain object properties are reset to pre-animation values. It could be that this is happening here for some reason. Put [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES]; outside of animation block, after [UIView commitAnimations]; and see what happens.

Comment: I tried putting it after [UIView commitAnimations];, but unfortunately it doesn't make a difference. Thank you though.

Comment: Did you try doing the same with the `parentViewController` solution?

Comment: Yes, I did ... still didn't work.

Comment: With some help I have scrapped everything and changed over to using a Modal View Controller, so I don't have to even hide the Navigation Bar anymore, since it automatically covers it up. Thank you everyone.

Comment: try NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController) in both methods (immediately before setNavigationBarHidden method)  to be sure you are sending the message to the correct nav controller

Answer (score 1):

For what I see in the code:
- you are adding a subview to your InstrumentsDetailViewController instance main view. 
- The subview is the main view of a WebViewController instance.

But...the WebViewController is never pushed or popped to your navigation stack. For this reason, your WebViewController instance has NO reference to your navigationController, and calling [self.navigationController] will send your setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES message to...nil

You can: 
- push/pop your WebviewController instance to the navigation stack, so it will have a reference to the navigationController.
or
- add your WebViewController instance as a CHILD of the InstrumentsDetailViewController and then call

```
[[[self parentViewController] navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

search for addChildViewController: